# Doubly ended queue

Tags: c, queue

*Can an input restricted deque be implemented using a linear queue instead of a circular queue?

Is this possibly (although not preferred)
Please verify!!!

Here is the code(but the time complexity for insertion from front is O(n);*

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define SIZE 5
    struct QUEUE{
        int queue[SIZE];
        int front,rear;
    }q;
    int isFull(){
        if(q.rear==SIZE-1)return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    int isEmpty(){
        if(q.front==-1 ||q.front>q.rear)return 1;
        return 0;   
    }
    void enqueue_back(){
        if(!isFull()){
            int ele;
            printf("\nEnter the element you want to enqueue: ");
            scanf("%d\n",&ele);
            q.queue[++q.rear]=ele;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nThe Queue is Full.");
        }
        if (q.front==-1){
            q.front++;
        }  
    }
    void enqueue_front(){
        if (q.front==-1){
            q.front++;
        } 
        if(!isFull()){
            for (int i=q.rear+1;i>q.front;i--){
                
                q.queue[i]=q.queue[i-1];
            }
            int ele;
            printf("\nEnter the element you want to enqueue: ");
            scanf("%d\n",&ele);
            q.queue[q.front]=ele;
            q.rear++;
        }
else{
            printf("\nThe Queue is Full.");
        }
        }
    void dequeue(){
        if(!isEmpty()){
            ++q.front;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nThe Queue is Empty.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are having?

Comment: Yes.  But you might not want to use a fixed-size array as the underlying data structure.  A linked list of some sort is more likely to be appropriate.

Comment: The O(N) insertion time indicates that the underlying data structure is suboptimal.  You need to identify (to yourself even if not in the question) what constraints you have on your code.  Is remove from front similarly an O(N) operation?  Does this matter?

Comment: A general deque cannot be efficiently implemented using only the operations of a queue because a deque must be able to remove an item from either side of the deque, but there is no way to remove the tail item on a queue other than by iterating through the other items of the queue and removing each to construct a new queue without the tail item. However, you have asked about “an input restricted deque” without defining what that is. If we restrict the input to a single item, then we can trivially implement a deque using a queue. What do you mean by “input restricted”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can an input restricted deque be implemented using a linear queue instead of a circular queue?

It can be, but as you noted it's going to be non-optimum. A standard queue supports two operations:

1. `push` - add an item to the queue.
2. `pop` - remove an item from the queue.

Items are removed in a first-in, last-out manner.

A double-ended queue supports four operations.

1. `push-back` - add an item to the back of the queue. This is the same as `push` in a standard queue.
2. `pop-front` - remove an item from the front of the queue. This is the same as `pop` in a standard queue.
3. `push-front` - add an item to the front of the queue.
4. `pop-back` - remove an item from the back of the queue.

It's possible to implement `push-front` and `pop-back` in terms of `push` and `pop`. In the case of `push-front`:

```
create a new queue
push the new item onto the new queue
for each item in the old queue
    pop from the old queue
    push onto the new queue
deleted the old queue
```

This operation, as you discovered, is O(n).

To implement `pop-back`

```
create a new queue
for each item on the old queue
    pop the item
    if the old queue is not empty
        push the item onto the new queue
    else
        delete the old queue
        return the item
```

Again, the complexity is O(n).

You can, however, create an input-restricted deque with a doubly-linked list. All you need is pointers to the head and tail of the list. It does not have to be circular.